# Jquery Curtain down effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a curtain down animation from the top (below navbar) to the bottom of the page, pushing on top of whatever page the user was on, but it should starts with a grey background during 500 milliseconds.
The page structure is something like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="viewport">
        content here
    </div>
</body>
```

and I'm using this:

```
$("#viewport").hide("blind", { direction: "down" }, 500, function (){
    // render target page
});
```

The problem is how make that effect with a grey background, which is different at the current one. Is there another way to achieve it?
thanks

Comment: Changed my code, it waorks now. I had started on jsfiddle and for some reason the spaces were going wrong and it was deleting code as I was typing so went on to my notepad and carried on but pasted the code from jsfiddle by mistake. you could change the curtain div to a curtain image,widths colors etc.etc to make it look better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited, I had posted the wrong code......Something like this ? obviously, change the page you want to load to something relevant.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
$("#changer").on("click", function(){
 
 $( "#curtain" ).animate({ height:"+=95%"  }, 4000,
function()   {    $("#viewport").load("PageYouWantToLoad.html",function(){
              $( "#curtain" ).animate({ height:"-=1px" });                          
          });           
      });
 });
});
```

```css
header{z-index:50;height:50px;background-color:grey;margin-bottom:30px;}
#curtain{background-color:grey;height:1px;min-width:100%;
z-index:3;position:absolute;top:52px;}
#newDiv{display:none;}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
<header><h3>header here <button id ="changer" >Click to change</button></h3></header>
<div id="curtain"> 
</div>
<div id="viewport">
Original page here  Original page here  Original page here  Original page here  
 </div>
```

#### EDITED, I had posted the wrong code. ooops....

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of the **jQuery plugin** [pagePiling.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/) which works with CSS3 to create a fluid movement but falls back to jQuery for old browsers.

Its quite nice.